# Padding in li tag

Tags: html, css

I am a developer and I don't know `CSS` properly. Here I am stuck with a simple problem. I am using `Sitefinity CMS` for development. I one of the page I used `ul` and `li`. `CSS` given by designer for `li` is as below

```
.listing li {
list-style: circle url(/images/default-source/main_library/bullet.gif?Status=Temp&sfvrsn=2);
margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

I just copied his `HTML` into my page but I observed `li` bullets are not at the same position as designer gave. I used `Developers Tools` and inspected. My `CMS` adding its own style to `li` as below

```
body, nav, ul, li, a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

When I disable `padding: 0;` then it appears to be at desired position. But how can I disable `padding: 0;` from development environment. Means any `CSS` that can remove `padding: 0;` effect?

Comment: Just overwrite it with a more specific selector.

Comment: I wrote li {padding : 1 }, did not work :(

Comment: `1` what? You need a unit. Try `padding:1px;`..

Comment: it padds from top, my li are proper at top but horizontally its misplacing. I tried `padding-left: 20px;` but its taking only text to right position not bullets.

Comment: Based on your edit, use: `.left_panel_inside li {
margin: 20px;
}`

Comment: it affecting whole contents, I want onli li to be affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `padding-left: 20px;` to the `ul`.

Add this to your `css`:
`.listing { padding-left: 20px; }`.

Edit: looks like you already have styles defined for `.listing`, so just append that to the `.listing` block, I believe it's **line 730** in `common.css`.

Comment: designer did not give `padding` in my case as it was not necessary. It is given by `CMS` so I cant use `!important`

Comment: You need to apply `padding-left: 20px;` to the ul. Add this to your css: `.listing { padding-left: 20px; }`. Edit: looks like you already have styles defined for .listing, so just append that to the .listing block, I believe it's line 730 in common.css.

Comment: Thanks..!! You comment is the answer, update it to help others. I already accepted and +1

Answer (score 0):

The more accurate the selector, the more precedence it has.

```
ul li { padding:5px; }

#my-Div div.another-div ul li { padding:0px; }
```

In this example, the more specific li element will use the 0px padding instead of the 5px. You can also add !important after an attribute if you need to ultimately override and existing style on an element.

```
ul li { padding:0 !important; }
```